# how to translate a graphics object from one point to another without modifiying it?

Tags: android, andengine

I'm trying for many hours to translate a mathematical path (a sin wave) from one coordinate position to another.. but either i'm stupid or something goes wrong.

I tryed this

```
    // Translate 
    for (int i=0; i < 300; i++) {
        coordinatesX[i] = coordinatesX[i] + ( 80 - coordinatesX[i]);
        coordinatesY[i] = coordinatesY[i] + (100 - coordinatesY[i]);
    }
```

Where 80 and 100 are the new coordinate position to which i wanna to translate my object. 
I tryed this

```
    // Translate 
    for (int i=0; i < 300; i++) {
        coordinatesX[i] = coordinatesX[i] + 80;
        coordinatesY[i] = coordinatesY[i] + 100;
    }
```

But all seems to partially work or work only if the wave has some angle ? 
I think I was missing some mathematics at school. I'm programming in Java using the AndEngine . May be there are some shortcuts to this elementar function.

The whole code:

```
    // define newpath
    float[] coordinatesX = new float[300]; 
    float[] coordinatesY = new float[300];
    // wave
    for (int i=0; i<300; i++){
        coordinatesX[i] =  i;
        coordinatesY[i] = (float)(20 * (Math.sin((-0.10 * coordinatesX[i]))));
        System.out.println(coordinatesX[i]);
        System.out.println(coordinatesY[i]);
        //coordinatesX[i] = coordinatesX[i] + centerX;
        //coordinatesY[i] = coordinatesX[i]+centerY;
    }


    // ROtate 
    for (int i=0; i<300; i++){
        coordinatesX[i] = ((coordinatesX[i] * (float)Math.cos(-10)) - (coordinatesY[i] * (float)Math.sin(-10))) + coordinatesX[i];
        coordinatesY[i] = (coordinatesX[i] * (float)Math.sin(-10)) + (coordinatesY[i] * (float)Math.cos(-10)) + coordinatesY[i];
    }

    // Translate 
    for (int i=0; i < 300; i++) {
        coordinatesX[i] = coordinatesX[i]+ (200);
        coordinatesY[i] = coordinatesY[i] + (300);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to translate a sine wave.  Adapt it according to your needs.

```
package math;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Curve translation example
 * User: Michael
 * Date: 1/10/12
 * Time: 7:56 PM
 */
public class TranslationExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double length = 1.0;
        int numPoints = 20;       
        List<Point2D.Double> curve = getCurve(length, numPoints);
        System.out.println("before translation");
        for (Point2D.Double point : curve) {
            System.out.printf("%10.6f %10.6f\n", point.getX(), point.getY());
        }
        Point2D.Double delta = new Point2D.Double(3.0, 4.0);
        curve = translateCurve(curve, delta);
        System.out.println("after  translation");
        for (Point2D.Double point : curve) {
            System.out.printf("%10.6f %10.6f\n", point.getX(), point.getY());
        }
    }

    private static List<Point2D.Double> translateCurve(List<Point2D.Double> curve, Point2D.Double delta) {
        List<Point2D.Double> translated = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();

        for (Point2D.Double point : curve) {
            translated.add(new Point2D.Double(point.getX()+delta.getX(), point.getY()+delta.getY()));
        }
        return translated;
    }

    private static List<Point2D.Double> getCurve(double length, int numPoints) {
        List<Point2D.Double> points = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();
        if ((length > 0.0) && (numPoints > 0)) {
            double dx = length / numPoints;
            double x = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < (numPoints - 1); ++i) {
                points.add(new Point2D.Double(x, Math.sin(2.0*Math.PI*x/length)));
                x += dx;
            }
            points.add(new Point2D.Double(length, Math.sin(2.0*Math.PI)));
        }

        return points;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh ..thank you very much. but it seems that the wave have some distortion when the angle is more than 45. Is there something wrong may be with the rotation function too?

Comment: "more than 45"?  I don't know what that means.  "rotation"?  There's no rotation going on here, just translation.  You do rotation using a matrix multiplication, like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix.  I'd prefer your upvote to your thanks.